# Image stitching with opencv using transformation matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to stitch 2 images together using previously-generated transformation matrix.

I know that opencv provides a framework (`cv::Stitcher` class) where transformation matrix is automatically estimated but I specifically want to use the previously-generated transformation matrix.

A good example of what I'm trying to do is this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/11/opencv-panorama-stitching/) but it doesn't specifically say how to use a particular transformation matrix to produce a mosaic and it's in python.

Is there a function in opencv which takes the transformation matrix as input and produces a mosaic/panorama? If yes, how do I do it?

I'm new to C++ (currently going through tutorial) and currently at the level of copy/pasting opencv source code to make their functions work. So it would be great if you could give a basic idea on how to use the function (structs/headers etc required). I'm familiar with matlab.

Comment: maybe https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp

Comment: use `cv::warpPerspective` to transform images according to a homography. You'll have to warp them to empty images of target size and you'll need some blending afterwards.

Comment: you could try to look a the `cv::Stitcher` code and add a "provideTransformatons` method. Then call `composePanorama` method.